# Google Apps Script: Deploy as web app and get url without 302 redirects

Tags: google-apps-script, stripe-payments

I have a test webhook setup in Stripe that posts to a google script that is deployed as a web app.

Google gives me the web app URL. That URL does one or more 302 redirects until it actually runs the script. This is incredibly annoying because the Stripe webhook is not following redirects.

How do I get the real URL for the web app and bypass these silly redirects?

Alternatively, how do I get Stripe to follow redirects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It is actually running the script when the Stripe webhook calls the web app URL, and the redirect is just to display the result.

I hadn't updated the deployed web app version to the latest code, which is why I thought the script wasn't being run.